# Python3: readline equavalent in select.select()

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnu, readline

In a Python script, programmers can import readline which then gives input() extended abilities (readline has many other uses). I am wanting to use select.select() in my scripts instead of input() because I like the timeout feature. However, when readline is imported, I cannot use the features that input() gains with readline. An example of the "extended features" I am referring to is being able to press the up-key and see the previous input or using the left and right arrow-keys to move the inline cursor to make changes to the input.

Question: How can I make select.select() have GNU-readline features? Is this even possible?

EDIT: Just in case any of you are curious as to what I am trying to accomplish, I made a terminal-based chatbot (kind of like Alicebot). I want the bot to get bored and do something else if the bit does not receive any input within a set amount of time. (https://launchpad.net/neobot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish this using the readline.set_pre_input_hook([function]) mechanism of the readline module.

Here's an example that times out after 10 seconds of no input - not implemented is a mechanism to *disable* the alarm if input is provided.

This would have to be done differently with threads since signals can't traverse threads. But, you get the basic idea..

I apologize for advance for this code, I'm at a coffee shop on my laptop and just kinda slapped it together. This is python2.7 code, but should basically be compatible with python3 - the concept is the important part.

I think you would want to put the alarm disable somewhere at the beginning of the input_loop() function if you wanted every line of input to have a timeout.

You should also take a look at the readline.c source in the Python module tree for more ideas.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import readline
import logging
import signal
import os

LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/completer.log'
HISTORY_FILENAME = '/tmp/completer.hist'

logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.DEBUG,)

class YouAreTooSlow(Exception): pass


def get_history_items():
    return [ readline.get_history_item(i)
             for i in xrange(1, readline.get_current_history_length() + 1)
             ]

class HistoryCompleter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.matches = []
        return

    def complete(self, text, state):
        response = None
        if state == 0:
            history_values = get_history_items()
            logging.debug('history: %s', history_values)
            if text:
                self.matches = sorted(h 
                                      for h in history_values 
                                      if h and h.startswith(text))
            else:
                self.matches = []
            logging.debug('matches: %s', self.matches)
        try:
            response = self.matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            response = None
        logging.debug('complete(%s, %s) => %s', 
                      repr(text), state, repr(response))
        return response

def input_loop():
    if os.path.exists(HISTORY_FILENAME):
        readline.read_history_file(HISTORY_FILENAME)
    print 'Max history file length:', readline.get_history_length()
    print 'Startup history:', get_history_items()
    try:
        while True:
            line = raw_input('Prompt ("stop" to quit): ')
            if line == 'stop':
                break
            if line:
                print 'Adding "%s" to the history' % line
    finally:
        print 'Final history:', get_history_items()
        readline.write_history_file(HISTORY_FILENAME)

# Register our completer function

def slow_handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    raise YouAreTooSlow()

def pre_input_hook():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, slow_handler)
    signal.alarm(10)

readline.set_pre_input_hook(pre_input_hook)
readline.set_completer(HistoryCompleter().complete)

# Use the tab key for completion
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')

# Prompt the user for text
input_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like readline was designed with this ability in mind ([link](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html)).

> An alternate interface is available to plain readline(). Some applications need to interleave keyboard I/O with file, device, or window system I/O, typically by using a main loop to select() on various file descriptors. To accomodate this need, readline can also be invoked as a `callback' function from an event loop. There are functions available to make this easy.

However it seems these bindings aren't implemented in Python.  Doing a quick search, there's a chap over [here](https://gist.github.com/jpic/1252105) who's done a POC by loading the function calls using CTypes.  This isn't ideal, but lacking any alternative, perhaps this is your only course of action.